# GRPC can support by java 6

Tags: java-6, grpc

Looks like grpc Prerequisites is java 7 or higher.

I got exception when install grpc.
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/protobuf/gradle/ProtobufPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

I have java 6 running locally. 
Could be a way grpc running with java 6?

Comment: http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/java.html Prerequisite is `Java7`, that means **no**.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle [no longer supports running under JDK 6](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes?_ga=1.237157891.261948072.1433184084#running-gradle-on-java-6-is-no-longer-supported). That said, gRPC is currently using an older version of Gradle that does work on JDK 6. But we also use a Protobuf plugin which doesn't work with JDK 6 (which is the error you see). Since we expect to upgrade to Gradle 3 soon, there is little point in fixing the compilation problem.

So while you must have JDK 7 to compile, the output from the compilation does support JRE 6. Look at [the artifacts on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.grpc%22); they use the older bytecode version for compatibility.

Java 6 is very old and has problems with things like TLS. The major reason Java 6 is supported is to ease Android usage, but even Android has some features of Java 7. I'd highly recommend moving to a newer JRE.